# Eloquent count() always returns 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
Item::select(['items.id', 'inventory.quantity'])
    ->leftJoin('inventory', 'items.id', '=', 'inventory.item_id')
    ->groupBy('items.id')
    ->count();
```

The `count()` method always returns 1 despite there being 20 rows to the results that are returned. Why might this be?

Here is the raw query from `DB::getQueryLog()`:

```
select 
    count(*) as aggregate
from
    `items`
        left join
    `inventory` ON `items`.`id` = `inventory`.`item_id`
group by `items`.`id`
```

Comment: Count gets the number of rows returned by the query. If you have only one item and multiple inventory entries, it will always return 1 because you're grouping by items.id. Have you tried using SUM()?

Comment: I need to know the number of rows of items, not rows of inventory (which is optional). The inventory table is presently empty. Just to see if the join was messing this up, I removed it and the `inventory.quantity` column. Still shows me `count() = 1` when I have 20 items in the result returned if I just change that to `get()`.

Comment: @VladCazacu I just discovered that if I remove `groupBy('items.id')` from the query, I get an accurate count. In fact, I've noticed that if I use `groupBy` on any query on any table I get just 1 on a count.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL for the count? Also, have you tried removing the select statement?

Comment: @VladCazacu Posted it as an edit. I also tried removing the `select` component but I still get the same value of 1. In fact, running that query in MySQL directly results in 20 rows of `1`. Would it matter if the engine was InnoDB vs MyISAM as to the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `count` returns only 1 row, always.

You would probably want:

```
Item::select(['items.id as id', 'inventory.quantity as quantity'])
 ->leftJoin('inventory', 'items.id', '=', 'inventory.item_id')
 ->groupBy('items.id')
 ->lists('quantity', 'id');
```

this will return an array with `id` as keys, and `quantity` as values. Otherwise use `get`, but never `count` if you want grouped results.

Comment: I actually need the number of rows that would be returned for use in pagination. I'm used to `count` only returning one row with the actual count of how many rows the query would have returned. For instance, in this case I expect a single row with a single column with the # `20`. However, `count` in this case is returning a list of rows and each row just has the # `1` in it. This is not only messing up my results for this query, but it is also messing up the results in Bllim Datatables so that pagination doesn't work there when Datatables fetches it automatically.

Comment: Do you know how aggregates work with group by clause?

Comment: Would seem that this counts each record in the group as opposed to all records in the result set. It seems that I would need to drop the `groupBy` clause and modify the `select` to have `DISTINCT items.id` instead?

Comment: Think about it. If it is `leftJoin` then count you're looking for is in fact `select count(*) from items`. You could also use `select (distinct items.id)`

Comment: `select (distinct items.id)` was the solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: select (distinct items.id) did not work in my case with laravel 8 . I see group by cause it to return 1. But if I do not add group by, it returns 53 in my example, but real count is 51 after grouping. So cant remove group by before calling count. I do not get.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the correct number of rows from a grouped result, and you don't care that much about the performance then you can call `get()` first and then call `count()` on that.

```
$count = Item::select(['items.id', 'inventory.quantity'])
    ->leftJoin('inventory', 'items.id', '=', 'inventory.item_id')
    ->groupBy('items.id')
    ->get()
    ->count();
```