# laravel query builder returns 0 record count but can iterate the results

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this simple query that groups email address. I noticed that when i use whereDate, it always returns 0 count when i use $users->count(). however, when i remove the date where clause, it returns the expected result. Can someone help me on this? thanks in advance!

```
    $users = Wfa::where('subscribe', 1)
                ->where('locale', $locale)
                ->whereDate($whichDateColumn, '=', $queryDate->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->groupBy('email')
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->get();

    dd($users) 
    /* output - returns 0 items
        Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#629
         #items: []
        }
    */

    /*this returns 0 results.*/
    $users->count();


    /*using the same query - this foreach works and can loop through the result set.*/
    foreach($users as $user){
         dd($user); #this shows the user details/collection
    }
```

I'm using laravel 5.0.35; upgrading is not an option :(

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. There's nothing visibly wrong with that query, but then we don't know the values of `$whichDateColumn` nor `$queryDate`, nor the data you're querying against to know if the date even exists.

Comment: thanks for your reply @fubar. Maybe someone experienced this problem. It's weird because the query looks fine and it's working. It's just that why can i loop through the results even if it says 0 results found.

Comment: What do you mean, why can you loop through the results? Edit your question to include the output of `dd($user)` for that query.

Comment: I've added comments about the  output of the query.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. If `$users` is empty, it won't suddenly have a value later in your code unless you change something else. Can you post all of your code between the query and using the `$users` value? What if you `dd($users)` immediately before the `foreach` ??

Comment: That's the exact code that I've run. I'm really puzzled why this is happening.  Been debugging this for hours

Comment: What other code do you have between the Eloquent query and the foreach? Is the foreach in a view? Do you have any view composers? Or global view data? There will be an explanation.

Comment: Can be this link useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315841/eloquent-count-always-returns-1

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys. @fubar that's the full code on my controller.  :(